# How to refactor code section in Angular2 HTML to shorter version?

Tags: angular, refactoring, directive

There is a long code in the Angular2 HTML template. 
How refactor this code in **< tr>** in a shorter version. Or move it to the @Directive.?

*activeContact* - it defined variable in @Component class, to have access to the selected row from the code?

*class **.active** from bootstrap3*

```
<tr 
  *ngFor="let contact of clientsData.contacts"
  [class.active] = "activeContact && contact.contactId == activeContact.contactId"
  (click)="activeContact = contact" class ="gm-pointer"
>
   <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
   <td>{{contact.surname}}</td>
</tr>
```

Changed:
Renamed < td> to < tr>

Answer (score 1):

you mean the code in the `<tr>`.

```
    <tr 
     *ngFor="let contact of clientsData.contacts"
     [class.active] = "isActive(contact)" (click)="activate(contact)" class ="gm-pointer"
     >
     <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
     <td>{{contact.surname}}</td>
    </tr>
```

define these methods inside your component class :

```
isActive(contact): boolean{
 return this.activeContact && contact.contactId == this.activeContact.contactId;
}

activate(contact): void{
 this.activeContact = contact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try ..

```
[class.active] = "activeContact === contact"
```

or if that wont work use safe navigation operator to shorten it slightly to ..

```
[class.active] = "contact.contactId == activeContact?.contactId"
```